# Upgrading Axis 1.1 to Axis 1.4 gives Schema Validation Error

Tags: upgrade, axis, webservice-client, validationerror, web-services-enhancements

I have upgraded Axis jar version from Axis 1.1 to Axis 1.4, after upgrade I am getting

**General Data Error:15002:Request/Response Schema Validation Error**

**Before upgrade:**

We have a legacy code(Client/Consumer) written using JDK1.3 and Axis 1.1, The code is able to consume web service exposed by our vendor.

**After upgrade**

After upgrading consumer with JDK1.6 and Axis 1.4, I need to update the code as shown below.

```
 // oper.setStyle(org.apache.axis.enum.Style.RPC);
// oper.setUse(org.apache.axis.enum.Use.ENCODED);
oper.setStyle(org.apache.axis.constants.Style.RPC);
oper.setUse(org.apache.axis.constants.Use.ENCODED);
```

The consumer code is not able to consume web service exposed by vendor.

**Stack trace**:

Any hint will be appreciated.

```
com.tdi.lh.cprm.customerlink.ServiceException: 200:General Data Error:15002:Request/Response Schema Validation Error
at com.tdi.lh.cprm.customerlink.CustomerInsuranceIdentifierFinder.find(CustomerInsuranceIdentifierFinder.java:68)
at CPRMLib.getIINumber(CPRMLib.java:1449)
at CPRMLib.main(CPRMLib.java:2060)
Caused by: 200:General Data Error:15002:Request/Response Schema Validation Error
at org.apache.axis.message.SOAPFaultBuilder.createFault(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:222)
at org.apache.axis.message.SOAPFaultBuilder.endElement(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:129)
at org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext.endElement(DeserializationContext.java:1087)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext.parse(DeserializationContext.java:227)
at org.apache.axis.SOAPPart.getAsSOAPEnvelope(SOAPPart.java:696)
at org.apache.axis.Message.getSOAPEnvelope(Message.java:435)
at org.apache.axis.handlers.soap.MustUnderstandChecker.invoke(MustUnderstandChecker.java:62)
at org.apache.axis.client.AxisClient.invoke(AxisClient.java:206)
at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invokeEngine(Call.java:2784)
at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2767)
at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2443)
at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2366)
at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:1812)
```

Answer (score 0):

After several days of research I found the reason for above error.

**I simply regenerated the entire client web service (stubs) code using axis 1.4 jar using command**

```
SET CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;C:\StockQuote\JDK16\lib\commons-discovery-0.2.jar
SET CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;C:\StockQuote\JDK16\lib\commons-lang-2.4.jar
SET CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;C:\StockQuote\JDK16\lib\activation.jar
SET CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;C:\StockQuote\JDK16\lib\axis-ant.jar
SET CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;C:\StockQuote\JDK16\lib\axis.jar
SET CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;C:\StockQuote\JDK16\lib\commons-collections-3.2.1.jar
SET CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;C:\StockQuote\JDK16\lib\commons-configuration-1.6.jar
SET CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;C:\StockQuote\JDK16\lib\commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
SET CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;C:\StockQuote\JDK16\lib\db2jcc4.jar
SET CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;C:\StockQuote\JDK16\lib\jaxrpc.jar
SET CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;C:\StockQuote\JDK16\lib\log4j-1.2.15.jar
SET CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;C:\StockQuote\JDK16\lib\mail.jar
SET CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;C:\StockQuote\JDK16\lib\saaj.jar
SET CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;C:\StockQuote\JDK16\lib\wsdl4j-1.5.1.jar
SET CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;C:\StockQuote\JDK16\lib\jsse.jar    
java org.apache.axis.wsdl.WSDL2Java https://localhost:8443/axis2/services/StockQuoteService?wsdl
```

**Note: We simply can't upgrade Axis1.1 --> to Axis 1.4. The existing code (Generated using Axis 1.1 jar earlier) needs to be regenerated using Axis 1.4 jar.**